# Automate a conversion in Wine with BASH (or Python ..)

Tags: command-line, wine, winetricks

There's one Windows program I've to run a few hundred times to convert old files to a new (open!) format. The command is simple:

```
wine /path/to/foobar.exe -convert /filepath/foobar.ext /filepath/foobar.newext
```

The program uses `.newext` to determine how to convert.

How can I automate this with bash?

Comment: Automate how ? Can you explain what exactly is a script supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a simple `for` loop:

```
for i in /file/path/*.ext;
do
 wine /path/to/foobar.exe -convert "$i.ext" "${i%.ext}.newext"
done
```

It's going to loop into `/filepath/` and converts all files with `.ext` extension to same name with `.newext`.

Each time it runs `wine` with for a single file with `.ext` format.

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful to you :)